# Nuxt.js - is it possible to set custom path/base to staticfiles' urls?

Tags: nuxt.js

**TLDR;**

How to change staticfiles path from `src="/_nuxt/<file>"` to e.g. `src="/static/frontend/<file>"` in Nuxt generated files?

---

Recently I've started a project using Nuxt.js and Django framework. Simply explained, with Nuxt I *generate* the `dist/` - my frontend app, and then copy it with Node.js to Django's static folder to be served.

In Django, the static files come built with a different path e.g `/static/frontend/<filename>.js`. However when I use `nuxt generate` to generate my app, there is - naturally - a path to files within the `dist` folder, in my case it's `/_nuxt/<filename>.js/`.

Is it possible to modify this "prefix" in `nuxt.config.js`? So far I know only about this option to set the base path for the whole app:

```
// nuxt.config.js

router: {
    base: '/app/'
},
```

But this is not a solution for me. Until now I have to replace the path occurences manually with Node.js and it might make things a bit messy. Any help appreciated!

Comment: build -> [publicPath](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build/#publicpath)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Lawrence Cherone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661872/lawrence-cherone) mentioned, [publicPath](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build/#publicpath) is the answer.