# Nuxt js. Is it possible to set custom path for js files that generated in _nuxt folder?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

Recently I've started a project with Nuxt js. But because the company use the same server with another application, and the url `https://my-company.com/_nuxt/` URL path already used by another application, I have to add `/customprefix/` to the application path. So the expected path URL is `https://my-company.com/customprefix/_nuxt/`.

I already tried to add `publicPath` like mentioned in accepted answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59027124/nuxt-js-is-it-possible-to-set-custom-path-base-to-staticfiles-urls) and also create a folder named `customprefix` in the root of the application but the files is still generated in `https://my-company.com/_nuxt/`

Here's my current `nuxt.config.js` file

```
export default {
  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  
  build:{
    publicPath: "/customprefix"
  },
  static:{
    prefix: true
  },
  
  head: {
    titleTemplate: '%s - nuxt-test',
    title: 'nuxt-test',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en'
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
      { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [
  ],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/vuetify
    '@nuxtjs/vuetify',
  ],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
  ],

  // Vuetify module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-vuetify
  vuetify: {
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
    theme: {
      dark: true,
      themes: {
        dark: {
          primary: colors.blue.darken2,
          accent: colors.grey.darken3,
          secondary: colors.amber.darken3,
          info: colors.teal.lighten1,
          warning: colors.amber.base,
          error: colors.deepOrange.accent4,
          success: colors.green.accent3
        }
      }
    }
  },

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
  }
}
```

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution. Turns out what I need to do is set the [base property on the router](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-router).

My final `nuxt.config.js` file :

```
import colors from 'vuetify/es5/util/colors'

export default {
  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  router:{
    base:"/customprefix/"
  },
  static:{
    prefix: true
  },
  
  head: {
    titleTemplate: '%s - nuxt-test',
    title: 'nuxt-test',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en'
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
      { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [
  ],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/vuetify
    '@nuxtjs/vuetify',
  ],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
  ],

  // Vuetify module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-vuetify
  vuetify: {
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
    theme: {
      dark: true,
      themes: {
        dark: {
          primary: colors.blue.darken2,
          accent: colors.grey.darken3,
          secondary: colors.amber.darken3,
          info: colors.teal.lighten1,
          warning: colors.amber.base,
          error: colors.deepOrange.accent4,
          success: colors.green.accent3
        }
      }
    }
  },

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
  }
}
```

What I add is :

```
 router:{
    base:"/customprefix/"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```
build: {
  publicPath: '/your-customprefix/'
},
```

Answer (score 0):

After each update, make sure to delete the 'node_modules' folder and the 'package-lock.json' file, and add the code as [kissu mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69158769/13569349)  in the 'nuxt.config.js'