# Serve a Nuxt app entirely prefixed (public files from baseURL)

Tags: routes, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I have a Nuxt app that I need to embed into another application.
E.g. my app should serve the following URLs:

```
/prefix/
/prefix/all
/prefix/_nuxt/...
/prefix/scripts/abcd.js
```

And every other route is served by another application.
I can handle the first 3 cases with

```
  app: {
    baseURL: '/prefix/',
  }
```

However, I also need to serve some public (static) files from the same `/prefix/`. I tried putting my scripts into `public/prefix`, but Nuxt was serving the app on those URLs instead of my files.
I know about `publicPath` from [Nuxt.js - is it possible to set custom path/base to staticfiles' urls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59027124/nuxt-js-is-it-possible-to-set-custom-path-base-to-staticfiles-urls), however, I have control only over my `/prefix/`.

Is there a way to serve public files from the baseURL somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your URL prefix in [`router.base`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-router#base) in nuxt.config.js:

```js
export default {
  router: {
    base: '/prefix'
  }
}
```

Then put your static files into the [`static` directory](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/static), and the entire app will be accessible at `/prefix`.

Comment: This method is working for generated static sites, but it breaks URL if the app is itself a bundle with only one html file (index.html).